# ROR 3 - Specifying specific view file, ignoring application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, render

I would like to specify a specific view file to render instead of the default one corresponding the REST architecture, meaning out of my 'create' function in the controller I would like to invoke the 'new' view file - which I believe can be done using:

```
def create
 .
 .
 render :new
end
```

But I also need that view file to ignore the cross-site layout specified in layouts/application.html.erb? is there a way to do that?

If it was out of the 'new' function, I could just state "render :layout => false" .. but I need it out of the 'create'

is there something like:

```
render :new, layout => false
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is this:

```
render :template => :new, :layout => false
```

Answer (score 3):

I' not sure about that, would have to try it, but i think that you can do this :

```
layout 'application', :except => :action_name
```

to exclude the action in your controller.

EDIT : I just tried it, it works indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you mentioned

```
def create
  render :new, :layout => false
end
```

You can then add the conditions like this

```
def create
  render :new, :layout => user_signed_in?
end
```

or the other way around depending on your need